# Backport C++14 return type deduction to C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How can I make this code c++11 compliant?

```
template <class ...Args>
auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
{
    return _delegate(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The code is part of a templated struct.
_delegate is a member and defined like below.

```
/// The implementation of the slot, as a delegate.  
typedef fastdelegate::FastDelegate<Signature> impl_delegate;    
impl_delegate _delegate;
```

The complete files can be found here. It is the slot.hpp.
https://github.com/miguelmartin75/Wink-Signals/tree/master/wink

Comment: I hope `_delegate` is a member function too.

Comment: What is `_delegate`?  A type?  A method?  A member?

Comment: `emit` appears to be [tag:C++11].

Comment: @JohanHallenberg So it is a member variable?

Comment: Please see above, it is a member of the struct  where the functions are declared.

Comment: @Yakk, you are correct. I did get the same error on that function from the compiler, but fixing the first code resolved also the emit. Thanks.

Comment: What was the reason for down voting this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a *trailing return type*:

```
template <class ...Args>
auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
    -> decltype(_delegate(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return _delegate(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vh31UhrpWdvOmbf1)

If your compiler is complaining about `_delegate` in the *trailing return type*, try using `std::declval</* type of '_delegate' */>()` instead.

---

Note that the code above might behave differently from the C++14 one. Consider the case where it's overloaded with the following member function:

```
auto operator()(...) const { }
```

In C++14, automatic return type deduction is not SFINAE-friendly, so the original  function in the question will probably cause an hard compilation error if `_delegate(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is ill-formed instead of SFINAE-ing away.

In C++11, `_delegate(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is part of the signature - if it is ill-formed, other overloads will have a chance to be selected.

Here's a [**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sgdGg3JDgaWm0R0r). Uncomment line `15` to see the changes.

Comment: I am afraid it did not help to remove the compile error from this line.
I get "_delegate was not declared in this scope, and no declaration were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow SFINAE-ing and the auto operator()(...) const {} case. If it is not too much asked for, can you please explain or guide me to where I can readup on this (I am not familiar with this C++14 functionality).

Comment: @JohanHallenberg What is `_delegate` in the original code?

Comment: @JohanHallenberg: edited my question, added live examples for both cases and a workaround for `_delegate`.

Comment: @JohanHallenberg: what's the type of `_delegate`? It's `bar`. Therefore you should use: `-> decltype(std::declval<bar>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, Many thanks. 
The std::declval</*type of _delegate */> solved it.